# JavaFX table column won't resize to prefWidth

Tags: java, javafx

I have a `TableView` in the center of a `BorderPane` with different prefWidth values for the columns. Inside SceneBuilder the columns are resized correctly according to the prefWidth value, but when I run the program the columns all have the same width (75.0). This is the .fxml file:

```
<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="1500.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ReportController">
   <center>
      <TableView fx:id="reportTableView" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="date" prefWidth="60.0" text="Date" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="company" prefWidth="75.0" text="Company" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="number" prefWidth="40.0" text="Number" />
          ...
        </columns>
         <columnResizePolicy>
            <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
         </columnResizePolicy>
      </TableView>
   </center>
   <bottom>
      <TitledPane text="Summary" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <content>
            <HBox alignment="CENTER">
               <children>
                  <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Details:">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="20.0" />
                     </font>
                  </Text>
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </content>
      </TitledPane>
   </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

And this is the code  that loads the frame:

```
    try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("report.fxml"));
            Parent parent = loader.load();

            Stage stage = new Stage(StageStyle.DECORATED);
            stage.setTitle("Tax Sheet Report");
            stage.getIcons().add(new Image("icons/icon.png"));
            stage.setScene(new Scene(parent));
            stage.setMaximized( true );
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you included the CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY to the table view.

The java doc says::

> Simple policy that ensures the width of all visible leaf columns in
> this table sum up to equal the width of the table itself.
>
> When the user resizes a column width with this policy, the table
> automatically adjusts the width of the right hand side columns. When
> the user increases a column width, the table decreases the width of
> the rightmost column until it reaches its minimum width. Then it
> decreases the width of the second rightmost column until it reaches
> minimum width and so on. When all right hand side columns reach
> minimum size, the user cannot increase the size of resized column any
> more.

Having said that, if you included the CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY on purpose, then you may need to add a bit more custom logic to satisfy the custom widths along with the policy.

**UPDATE:**

If you want to acheive a feature something like "percentWidth" feature in GridPane, you can try the below approach.

The idea is :

- Create a custom TableColumn that has a new property "percentWidth"
- Create a custom TableView that has a listener to its widthProperty and adjust the columns prefWidth based on the percentWidth.
- Import these controls in fxml and update the fxml with the new controls.

***CustomTableColumn.java***

```
public class CustomTableColumn<S, T> extends TableColumn<S, T> {
    private DoubleProperty percentWidth = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

    public CustomTableColumn(String columnName) {
        super(columnName);
    }

    public DoubleProperty percentWidth() {
        return percentWidth;
    }

    public double getPercentWidth() {
        return percentWidth.get();
    }

    public void setPercentWidth(double percentWidth) {
        this.percentWidth.set(percentWidth);
    }
}
```

***CustomTableView.java***

```
public class CustomTableView<S> extends TableView<S> {
    public CustomTableView() {
        widthProperty().addListener((obs, old, tableWidth) -> {
            // Deduct 2px from the total table width for borders. Otherwise you will see a horizontal scroll bar.
            double width = tableWidth.doubleValue() - 2;
            getColumns().stream().filter(col -> col instanceof CustomTableColumn)
                    .map(col -> (CustomTableColumn) col)
                    .forEach(col -> col.setPrefWidth(width * (col.getPercentWidth() / 100)));
        });
    }
}
```

***Updated fxml code:***

```
<CustomTableView fx:id="reportTableView" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
    <columns>
      <CustomTableColumn fx:id="date" percentWidth="35" text="Date" />
      <CustomTableColumn fx:id="company" percentWidth="40" text="Company" />
      <CustomTableColumn fx:id="number" percentWidth="25" text="Number" />
      ...
    </columns>
</CustomTableView>
```

*Please note that sum of all columns percentWidth should be equal to 100 for better results :)*

A full working demo of this implementation(non fxml) is below: *(I updated the code to fix the horizontal scroll bar in the gif)*

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PercentageTableColumnDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        ObservableList<Person> persons = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        persons.add(new Person("Harry", "John", "LS"));
        persons.add(new Person("Mary", "King", "MS"));

        CustomTableColumn<Person, String> fnCol = new CustomTableColumn<>("First Name");
        fnCol.setPercentWidth(30);
        fnCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().firstNameProperty());

        CustomTableColumn<Person, String> lnCol = new CustomTableColumn<>("Last Name");
        lnCol.setPercentWidth(25);
        lnCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().lastNameProperty());

        CustomTableColumn<Person, String> cityCol = new CustomTableColumn<>("City");
        cityCol.setPercentWidth(45);
        cityCol.setCellValueFactory(param -> param.getValue().cityProperty());

        CustomTableView<Person> tableView = new CustomTableView<>();
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(fnCol, lnCol, cityCol);
        tableView.setItems(persons);

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(tableView);
        VBox.setVgrow(tableView, Priority.ALWAYS);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Table demo");
        stage.show();
    }

    class CustomTableColumn<S, T> extends TableColumn<S, T> {
        private DoubleProperty percentWidth = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

        public CustomTableColumn(String columnName) {
            super(columnName);
        }

        public DoubleProperty percentWidth() {
            return percentWidth;
        }

        public double getPercentWidth() {
            return percentWidth.get();
        }

        public void setPercentWidth(double percentWidth) {
            this.percentWidth.set(percentWidth);
        }
    }

    class CustomTableView<S> extends TableView<S> {
        public CustomTableView() {
            widthProperty().addListener((obs, old, tableWidth) -> {
                // Deduct 2px from the total table width for borders. Otherwise you will see a horizontal scroll bar.
                double width = tableWidth.doubleValue() - 2;
                getColumns().stream().filter(col -> col instanceof CustomTableColumn)
                        .map(col -> (CustomTableColumn) col)
                        .forEach(col -> col.setPrefWidth(width * (col.getPercentWidth() / 100)));
            });
        }
    }

    class Person {
        private StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private StringProperty city = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public Person(String fn, String ln, String cty) {
            setFirstName(fn);
            setLastName(ln);
            setCity(cty);
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName.get();
        }

        public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName.set(firstName);
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName.get();
        }

        public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName.set(lastName);
        }

        public String getCity() {
            return city.get();
        }

        public StringProperty cityProperty() {
            return city;
        }

        public void setCity(String city) {
            this.city.set(city);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Is there a way to also make the cells stretch to the width of the table, but preserve their ratios with respect to the preferred width?

Comment: I think you can consider implementing a custom percentWidth feature to TableColumn and a custom TableView to adjust the column widths. I updated the answer with the required details.

Comment: Follow on questions like this are usually best when asked as new questions which refer back to the original.

Answer (score 2):

Use `UNCONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY` instead of `CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY` as a column policy of `TableView`.